# Recaptcha V3 returns score 0.1 after plus/minus 20 times submitting form (while adjusting these pages)

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha-v3

I have a register page where I use Recaptcha for the first form with the users email (I am working on it now). Then it hides that form and i remove the Recaptcha token div. Then the name streetnumber etc. comes up `show()` and that needs to be filled in as a new Recaptcha form. That works great and perfect.

Is it normal that the Recaptcha V3 returns 0.1 after I pushed the 2 form buttons like 20/30 times WITHOUT 1 wrong click. So 20/30 times in a row of successful clicks on the Recaptcha form the 31st time it will give me a 0.1 score.

Is this normal?

It could be that Recaptcha V3 thinks I am a spammer if I click 30 times in 1,5/2 hours.

Comment: I understand you are coding in `PHP`, please always tag your questions accordingly to get the appropriate audience to see your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey Wiktor thanks for your answer. Yes i tagged "PHP" and recaptcha-v3. What is there more to tag? Jquery maybe then?

Comment: Maybe some code to repro? Sorry, I can't help here.

Comment: Maybe you can just skip the recaptcha validation during development

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for your answer. Yes that would be an option. But i still need to test if recaptcha works if i fill in 2 times the FORM. Wonder if the next day recaptcha fails. So i need to test it just filling a form as a normal user.

Comment: You can't really be sure IMO because Google use real-time signals to _predict_ the likelihood the request was from a bot, but I use it, and it never give me any trouble, and I have a lot of visitors on my site

Comment: @AlonEitan I will test(act as a normal user) it this weekend and will let you know if you don't mind. Cause if that still gives me error on recaptcha i hope you can share your php recaptcha code. But we will see. Have a nice day/evening and i am glad someone reacted thank you very much!

Comment: It is quite common for an app's own developers to get lower scores on their own apps. Repeated use of the same form is something a malicious user or a bot would do! Unfortunately it's also something we do to our own apps. :)