# pattern html to preg_match PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using this next pattern for HTML `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d`.

I want exactly the same pattern for PHP `preg_match()` for server-side validation. Does someone know this? Is there some kind of converter or something.

The pattern is for `12/12/1999` and also `12-12-1999` and as you can see it only allows year 1900 and 2000.

I searched online for the pattern, but I couldn't find the combination pattern on having `12/12/1999` and also `12-12-1999` + 1900 and only the year 2000.

And does someone know a good website to convert these kind of things or to make preg_match PHP or patterns HTML?

Comment: Did it not work with preg_match? Did you try `~` as a delimiter instead of `/`?

Comment: its a date, just include a `if(DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', ..` as part of your validation, its not expensive calling it twice and can support any formats

Comment: You need `preg_match('~^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1(?:19|20)\d{2}$~', $text)`, else you will match the pattern in longer strings and you might match `12-12.1988` like strings where the delimiters are not consistent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help Wiktor but it worked on next solution. `preg_match('/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/', '12-12-9999', $matches);`

Comment: So, you want to match `12-12-9999` in `323434512-12-99993423534`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ooh shit, oke. Yeah i noticed it just now. So yours will have a limit on 2-2 and 4 ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does it also check if its a valid email like this is not > 33-33-2020? Or not

Comment: `33-33-2020` is not a valid email. My suggestion is based on the fact HTML patterns are anchored by default while `preg_*`  patterns are not. I also think the delimiters should be consistent, else, you may match something that is not what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry wrong question from me. My question is if your code also checks if the next date is wrong `33-33-2020` Or does it continue with your code. Because you said earlier `1212-1212-9999` this will be blocked right?

Comment: See [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/tVEwwD/4). Your regex does  not match `33-33-2020`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's perfect, very handy website also. If you make it inside a answer. I will accept yours and unaccept the one below? Because people may be searching for this i want the best solution to be on top.

Comment: It still occurs to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974490/converting-javascript-regex-to-php gives you all you need to convert any JS regex to PHP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah still little unclear how to do it. Too bad there is not website to convert them. I am checking the Javascript Regex and the website you gave me shows no error if i use them AS php regex. Need to test it still.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey Wiktor do you maybe this question i made day's ago nobody answers. It's about recaptcha V3 > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542914/can-someone-confirm-please-recaptcha-v3-returns-score-0-1-after-plus-minus-20-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is escape the forward slashes (`/`).  Escape forward slashes with a backslash, like `\/`

So this would be your pattern:

`(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d`

```
preg_match('/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/', '12-12-9999', $matches);
```

Here's an example on regex101 of it matching both dates using the PHP regex engine (PCRE):

https://regex101.com/r/tVEwwD/3

OR, another alternative is to just use a different delimiter, like so:

```
preg_match('~(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d~', '12/12/9999', $matches);
```

Notice the `~` character, before and after the regex pattern.  That's the delimeter.

Comment: Oh yeah i think someone downvoted because there is no limit on the dates as Wiktor mentioned. `preg_match('~^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\1(?:19|20)\d{2}$~', $text)` I still need to test it though